# How to update cascaded columns in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a entity "feed" which is parent for another another entity "record" as below

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="feed",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Record> Record;
```

reference columns are feed_id and sequence

What I want is, when I change the sequence and save the feed entity, my record sequence should be updated as well.

```
Map<String,String> error;
Feed feed = _objMapperDataService.getSequence(a_mapperFeed.getPROJECT_ID‌​(),a_mapperFeed.getF‌​DID());
int seqNo = feed.getFeedSequence()+1;
feed = _objMapperDataService.getFeedBySequence(a_mapperFeed.getPROJ‌​ECT_ID(),a_mapperFee‌​d.getFDID());
feed.setFeedSequence(seqNo); 
error = _objMapperDataService.saveOrUpdateFeed(feed);
if(error.get("success").equals("true")){ 
     a_mapperFeed.setID(null);
     a_mapperFeed.setSEQUENCE(0);
     error = _objMapperDataService.saveOrUpdateFeed(mapperFeedToFeed(a_ma‌​pperFeed)); 
}
return error;
```

I tried cascadeAll but it does not work and gives the below error while saving

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKCU5674BI4F1DDPKM9QV2EQKI9: PUBLIC.RECORD FOREIGN KEY(FDID, SEQUENCE) REFERENCES PUBLIC.FEED(FDID, SEQUENCE) (0, 0)";\
```

Comment: Show the definition of your database tables. Show code where you update and store the `Feed`.

Comment: Map<String,String> error;
  Feed feed = _objMapperDataService.getSequence(a_mapperFeed.getPROJECT_ID(),a_mapperFeed.getFDID());
  int seqNo = feed.getFeedSequence()+1;
  feed = _objMapperDataService.getFeedBySequence(a_mapperFeed.getPROJECT_ID(),a_mapperFeed.getFDID());
  feed.setFeedSequence(seqNo);
  error = _objMapperDataService.saveOrUpdateFeed(feed);
  if(error.get("success").equals("true")){
   a_mapperFeed.setID(null);
   a_mapperFeed.setSEQUENCE(0);
   error = _objMapperDataService.saveOrUpdateFeed(mapperFeedToFeed(a_mapperFeed));
  }
  return error;

Comment: saveOrUpdateFeed function calls the save from crud repository which throws the above error

Comment: How do you expect the list of `Record`s to be updated with the code provided?

Comment: I have used "findby" to get all the data from db and then edited the sequence.

my feed.java entity contains below line

@OneToMany(mappedBy="feed",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
 private List<Record> Record;

so when i do "findby"..i get record list along with feed

now as i have used CascadeType.ALL,i expect the record table to be updated when i save feed

Comment: You don't do any actual update to record as far as I can see.

Comment: I have incremented the sequence number before calling save. only sequence column is updated.